# What's the meaning of the expression "get handed" in this phrase?

Tags: word-in-context

What's the meaning of the expression "get handed" in the following passage?

> I only told my wife a few days ago that the reason I bought the house we now live in was because of the building I saw in the garden. How often do you **get handed** a recently-built, high quality brick building on your land that is structurally sound and ripe to be turned into a studio?

Comment: I read the body of your question and, briefly, had no idea what you were asking—and I was wondering what your telling your wife about a building had anything to do with a question about grammar. Then I read the title of your question again and understood. For clarity, I added your actual question to body of the question itself and I put the passage into block quotes—to make it obvious that it's not part of your own question.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, Jason. I'll do it this way from now on. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some contexts, "to get handed [something]" would mean "to be given [something] free of charge." Here, that's not the case, but the phrase still conveys the idea that having the opportunity to buy this particular house, with that brick building in the garden, was a very lucky break – not because it was free, but because it would be hard to find another house that came with a "recently-built, high quality brick building… that is structurally sound and ripe to be turned into a studio."

Please note that in other contexts, "get handed [something]" can have very different meanings, including negative ones.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the clarification. Now the whole phrase starts to make sense to me.